# How are inline fractions written in modern Hebrew? Which way does the slash tilt?

Tags: hebrew, mathematical-language

The question [Why does SpaceIL's Beresheet landing graphics show m\s instead of m/s?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40584/12102) in Space Exploration refers to the display of velocities shown in the cropped screenshot below of a different video I found that showed it in larger size.

This question post is specific to Hebrew and not English; when writing in-line fractions (two numbers separated with a slash):

1. Is the numerator on the right and the denominator on the left?
2. If a tilted slash is used, which way does it lean?

In other words if I wanted to write one-half (0.5), how exactly would it look?

If it turns out that the closest slash is indeed `\` instead of `/` as is used in scientific writing in many/most left-to-right written languages, this might also address the linked question.

---

Image is a screenshot of a display of data from the SpaceIL Beresheet spacecraft during its Moon landing attempt. It is in English but in the display of speeds, the heading is `Velocity [m\s]` where one would expect the units to be written `[m/s]` with a "forward slash" which tilts to the right. A "backslash" is shown in the display.

[image: Beresheet Moon Landing scientific display video screenshot] from [video](https://youtu.be/MHqjVMTdjM8?t=515)

Comment: when down voting a new user's first question on a site, the courtesy of a helpful comment is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of Hebrew sources that use a forward slash, such as this jelly doughnut recipe https://www.mako.co.il/food-recipes/recipes_column-holidays/Recipe-2af8ad052bb3431006.htm

> ‏כוס ריבה אדומה 1/2
>
> ‏1/2 כוס אבקת סוכר

which translates to

> 1/2 cup red jam
>
> 1/2 cup powdered sugar

Comment: are there also sources that use the backslash as well, or is the forward slash most often or always used?

Comment: unfortunately, google search gets rid of punctuation, so I couldn't get results that were useful for the size of "מתכון 1/2" vs. "מתכון 1\2" (recipe 1/2 v. recipe 1\2)

Comment: I found this particularly difficult to research with a search engine myself! "how to write fractions in Hebrew" returns a Hebrew translation of "fractions" for example.